# Is there any ways to speed up Hibernate SessionFactory building?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sessionfactory

I have more than 2 thousand entities in my SessionFactory config, but it takes too long to run buildSessionFactory() Hibernate Core method. Sometimes it can be more than 5 minutes. Is there any ways to speed it up?

Comment: Have you profiled where the time goes? I could imagine that with 2K entities if it's doing schema verification it'll take a while.

Comment: Kayaman, thanks. Is it really necessary to perform schema verification? What if I turn it off? Does it give some perfomance boost?

Comment: Give it a try and find out.

Comment: Kayaman, no noticeable boost at all :(

Comment: Then it's profilin' time.